# Magento Can't login to my account on ios server

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ipad, magento

I am working on magento site https://www.smkd.com/index.php.
It works me fine for every browser except IOS server.
When i  click on to my account or login,and fill my account details,then  it redirects me on the same page and not allowed to me login.
I have removed all the extension but still i am having this problem and can not login to my account.
I am using the ultimo theme.
Can you guys please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are talking about is of cookie problem.If you can log in to your admin panel then go to

> "System->Configuration->Web"

Under "Session Cookie Management" You will see the field for "Cookie Domain", add your domain there for your case ".com" save and try login again.If doesnot work try putting "/" on "cookie path".

If you cannot login to your admin panel then you have to edit it in "core_config_data" table.

Hope this will work.