# Newly installed Magento, invalid login even with correct user and pass

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm using magento 1.9, and made sure that my var and media folder's permissions are on 777.

I can't seem to login into the admin panel even with the correct login details.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about administering a Magento installation, not about programming. It seems better suited to the [Magento Stack Exchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their FAQ to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: That said, it still seems likely the problem is with reading and writing the session store. Is there anything else that's unusual about your Magento installation that could be a clue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be frequent in many installation,i guess it the the cookie problem.

Have a look at the link below it may solve the issue.

https://www.facebook.com/notes/rohit-patel/after-installing-magento-cant-log-in-to-admin-panel/256699557722386

If the above link doesnot help try following the answer that i have provided in below link this should work.

[Magento Can't login to my account on ios server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169868/magento-cant-login-to-my-account-on-ios-server/27183375#27183375)

Hope this will help.