# Magento admin worked in IE Browser but Did not working on Firefox and Chrome. I hosted magento on IIS webserver

Tags: magento, admin

I am using magento v1.9 for my product development. I hosted the same on IIS webserver and working with Windows 7. I not able to login to admin panel using chrome and firefox browser. But, Same configuration will perfect with IE Browser.

Comment: Are you working on localhost?

Comment: are you configured your cookie settings from configuration in magento

Comment: I am working with our local server, No we haven't change any cookie settings. I have doubt this might be becuase of cookie setting. If i commented cookie setting as found under file  app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php then i can see the magento dashboard but normal magento functionality which work on cookie won't be worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cookie problem. I had also faced same problem as yours in which there is a problem with some browser while logging in to admin panel.For that you need to make some amendments in your cookie domain field.

Below is the link where i have provided answer to the similar type of problem have a look at it and try to configure as per your requirement.

[check out answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169868/magento-cant-login-to-my-account-on-ios-server/27183375#27183375)

Hope this will help.